# Can't login to facebook using Opera

Tags: facebook, opera

After typing my details in and clicking login Opera takes me to an error page. This doesn't happen in Chrome, Firefox or Opera on other OSs.

The page shows the error: Internal communication error. It then offers to search for https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1

Regenerating the `.Opera` folder does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera cannot check the certificate of any pages.
Report to opera community to further help.

Comment: Looks like its a bug in Opera. I'm going to have to wait for a fix in a future patch.